# Unable to use AND logical operator between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the following error I am getting:

> Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

```sql
select p.BusinessEntityID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, bea.BusinessEntityID, bea.AddressID
from Person.Person as p
left join
Person.BusinessEntityAddress as bea on 
p.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
where bea.BusinessEntityID and bea.AddressID is NOT NULL
```

Comment: where bea.BusinessEntityID IS NOT NULL and bea.AddressID is NOT NULL`

Comment: If `bea.AddressID` should not be `NULL` why are you `LEFT JOIN`ing to `Person.BusinessEntityAddress`? It is *impossible* for `bea.AddressID` to not have the value `NULL` if no row was found. *If* `bea.AddressID` isn't `NULL`able, the `WHERE` isn't needed at all; just use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Is `BusinessEntityAddress` a many-to-many relation? Why is `AddressID` allowed to be NULL in this case? If an entity has no address, delete the row

Comment: In truth, the `bea.BusinessEntityID IS NOT NULL` isn't needed at all, @Sergey . If `bea.AddressID` isn't `NULL` then by definition `bea.BusinessEntityID` can't be `NULL` either, as `p.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID` cannot be true if it were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where expression is not clear. you must write like

```
where bea.BusinessEntityID Is Not NuLL and bea.AddressID is NOT NULL
```

or remove it like

```
 where bea.AddressID is NOT NULL
```

> `bea.BusinessEntityID` checked on join, you don't need it. remove is better

Comment: @Larnu You're correct, basically these Null records in the right table are the ones that are not matching with the left table.

Comment: @Panagiotis No, it is not a many to many relationship however the purpose to use the where clause with NOT NULL was to check if we can remove NULL records from the columns.